# Where do Client-only rules execute on a single profile with multiple Outlooks open?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, mail-rule

I have two outlooks 2007 open on two different machines logged in to the same account. The issue is I have is with client-only rules for sound alerts executing intermittently. All other rules work correctly, because they are run on the Exchange Server, but the client-only ones seem to pick and choose when to produce sounds. Is there something I can do to make my client-only rules run reliably on one particular instance of outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side rules seem to execute on the last outlook instance where said rule was updated. There is no indication on the rules screen however which client side rules will actually execute on a particular client.